# Get every year last date values from data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Data frame like this(from 1971 to 2021).

```
             date  AUDUSD Close
 42    2020-12-29        0.7608
 41    2020-12-30        0.7676
 40    2020-12-31        0.7709
 39    2021-01-04        0.7664
 38    2021-01-05        0.7767
 37    2021-01-06        0.7799
 36    2021-01-07        0.7767
```

now i want to get every year last date values from data frame. above example i want line No 40. Any one know how to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) by years:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.year).last().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
        date  AUDUSD Close
0 2020-12-31        0.7709
1 2021-01-07        0.7767
```